# Pro licence error - Craft is unable to purchase an edition upgrade at this time

Tags: license

I'm trying to purchase a pro license for Craft 2. The site was on a staging server which is now uploaded to the live server. At first, there were 2 warning messages. First saying running Craft Pro on Solo license. And another saying you are using a license belonging to the staging site.

I removed the license .key from the config folder and cleared the cache and this re-created the license and cleared the staging site message. However, when I go to purchase a pro license it goes through the fields and ends with a message.

*Craft is unable to purchase an edition upgrade at this time.*

Does anyone have any idea what is going on and how to resolve this? The site needs to go live today.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

According to their Tweet it seems there was an error on P&T's end: 
https://twitter.com/CraftCMS/status/1085975322443448321